# IIS and Azure using old assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, azure

As I am building my project in visual studio, I build my entire solution and check `http://localhost` for my dev environment (using standard iis webapp), and when I want to push to staging I publish to my azure env.  All of a sudden, whenever I build out my solution, its referencing some old compiled .dll of my projects because the same bugs keep coming up.  I am sure of this because when I go into `myproject/bin` folder and take those dlls out seperately and overwrite them in my iis bin folder or on my azure server, the bugs are gone and my most recent code is there.  Im not quite sure why it keeps doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into visual studio under my references and selected my dlls and changed  "Specific Version" to true, then rebuild the solution, then turn "Specific Version" back to false.  It's weird because its not 100% consistent but it works most of the time.